# A fatal error occurred when attempting to transcode the character encoding of the document. ("system.text.utf8encoding")

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

I do not know how to make a simple website complete, it's faulty social networking login popup (popup does not finish and completes, duplicate error and i do not know where it is to handle reason And currently it was like this when i checked at w3 can see through and help me no, i do not know englis

Comment: At SO you need to show the code you have tried and ask for help where you are stuck.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">   
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LpjnzVogzBZFbe3wAFsS_jkj5-tq7jwf1nkk4tp4ok8" />
  <title>{%if page_title == 'All'%}Tất cả {%else%}{{ page_title }}{%endif%}{% if current_tags %} tagged "{{ current_tags | join: ', ' }}"{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} - Trang {{ current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains store.name %} {{ store.name }}{% endunless %  
</title> {% include 'iwish' with 'iwishhead' %}

Comment: @TênNguyễn Please do not post the code in the comment. It is unreadable. Instead edit your question to add the code.